# loading files via filedialog in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created uploading text files with this code:

```
var koloader = new THREE.FileLoader();
    koloader.load('Koordinate.txt',
    function ( data ) {

    const kord = data.split('\n').map(line =>line.trim()).map(line => line
  .split(' ')                // split by ' '
  .map(parseFloat),line => line
  .split(' ')                // split by ' '
  .map(parseFloat))               // and parse the parts to numbers
.map(([ x, y, z, w]) => ({ x, y, z, w }));
    var dolzina = kord.length;
    dolzList = dolzina;
    //var pointList = [];
    for( let i = 0; i < dolzina; i++){

    var temp = new THREE.Vector3(kord[i].x,kord[i].y,kord[i].z);
    pot[i] = new THREE.Vector3(temp.x,temp.y,temp.z);
    casi[i] = kord[i].w;
    droneFlightLine.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(kord[i].x,kord[i].y,kord[i].z));
    }

    flighLine = new THREE.Line( droneFlightLine, materialG );

},
```

this code gets x,y,z and time coordinates which I have saved in Koordinate.txt file.
I would like now create a file dialog (maybe input tag ) and load file via this dialog.. Example: I click on button, choose this txt file and it loads me the file like this code does..

Comment: you are not asking a specific question. what have you tried; how is it failing. there are many libraries that do what you want, from jquery to bootstrap.

Comment: I have searched for input tag.. but don't know how to use it. I am used to c# .. example you give to a button id and then in you code you just do like button.text.. but I don't know how to do it in javascript